# How to fetch user attributes from ADFS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, adfs

I am new to ADFS and trying to integrate Single Sign On using ADFS in Ruby on Rails. So service provider or client is RoR app and idP is ADFS. I want to have 2 features supported as part of integration where first part is Authentication and other part is syncing some user data from AD. I found content on how to authenticate a user using ADFS however I am having hard time figuring out how to fetch sync user data (some status related fields that need to be synced in the RoR app frequently from the AD). I have read about claims and how we can map attributes in AD to claims. However I am not able to understand how can I use it to efficiently fetch few thousand users data and sync it frequently.
Is there a way to do it in Ruby. What needs to be configured in ADFS. Can someone point me in right direction.

Answer (score 0):

ADFS is only about authentication.

It has nothing to do with AD provisioning.

You need to do this yourself using LDAP queries on AD.